# Advanced text formatting in matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title() ... to align two rows in title differently

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to format text in matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title() to get for example:

Two rows, each with different alignment: 1. row aligned to the left, the next row to the center? Font size, or other font parameters for every row?

For example, in title text here, I want the chart identification: 'a)' to be aligned to the left and the next line to the center:

```
ax[0].set_title("a)\nsecond title row", fontsize = 14, loc='left')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new line is added to the string to be placed on the left. Now I've set up a normal title. Does this meet the intent of your question?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(range(10))

ax.set_title('second title row')
ax.set_title('a)\n', loc='left')
# ax.set_title('Right Title', loc='right')

plt.show()
```

[image]